# About the import method of redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am a 2-month front end developer.

I studied React at the same time as I joined the company,
so there are many parts I do not know well.

I am currently analyzing the code to proceed with code maintenance,
but there is an esoteric part of the code.

First, In the saga, There is no part where the action function is imported. (even in the root saga.)

So, Is it possible to implicitly import in the code?

I'm attaching some of the code to help you understand.

rootSaga.js

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";

import watcherLogin from "store/sagas/login";
import watcherSignUp from "store/sagas/signup";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    watcherLogin(),
    watcherSignUp(),
  ]);
}
```

watcherLogin() > index.js

```
export { default } from "./watcherLoginSaga"
```

watcherLogin() > watcherLoginSaga.js

```
import { all, put, fork, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import { fetchData } from "store/sagas/baseSaga";

function* onRequestLogin(action) {
  const payload = action.payload;
  const { history } = payload;
  const successAction = (res) => {

    const cookies = new Cookies();
    cookies.set("hdmKey", res.data, {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 3600,
    });
    return function* () {

      const payload = res;
      yield put({
        type: "login/GET_USERINFO_REQUEST",
        payload: {
          method: "get",
          api: "getUserInfo",
          // token: res.data.key,
          history,
        },
      });
      yield put({
        type: "login/LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
        payload,
      });
      yield put({
        type: "base/IS_LOGGED",
        payload,
      });
      yield history.push("/");
    };
  };
  const failureAction = (res) => {

    return function* () {

      yield put({
        type: "base/SHOW_MODAL",
        payload: {
          dark: true,
          modalName: "alert",
          modalContent: "login failure",
          modalStyle: "purpleGradientStyle",
          modalTitle: "Wait!",
        },
      });
    };
  };
  yield fork(fetchData, payload, successAction, failureAction);
}
...

export default function* watcherLoginSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest("login/LOGIN_REQUEST", onRequestLogin),
  ]);
}
```

loginModule > index.js

```
export { default } from "./loginModule";
```

loginModule > loginModule.js

```
import createReducer from "store/createReducer";
import { changeStateDeep } from "lib/commonFunction";

export const types = {
  LOGIN_REQUEST: "login/LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS: "login/LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
  ...
};
export const actions = {
  loginRequest: (payload) => ({
    type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST,
    payload,
  }),
...
};
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: {
    isLogged: false,
    ...
  },
};
const reducer = createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, {

  [types.ON_LOGIN]: (state, action) => {
    state.data.isLogged = true;
  },
  [types.LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => {
    state.data.isLogged = true;
    state.data.key = action.payload?.key || "key";
  },
...
});
export default reducer;
```

I would appreciate it if you could help even a little.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem/question here. `takeLatest("login/LOGIN_REQUEST", onRequestLogin)` inside **watcherLogin() > watcherLoginSaga.js** is doing action-saga mapping. Which means that when you `dispatch` login/LOGIN_REQUEST action, request will be handled by `onRequestLogin()` saga function.

Comment: Oh, I understood what you were saying. In other words, are you saying that mapping is possible without importing the action function?

Comment: What do you mean by `action function`? Can you paste some sample here in comment section? I need to be sure that we're on the same page.

Comment: oh... The action function I'm talking about is inside loginModule> loginModule.js.

Comment: export const types = {
  LOGIN_REQUEST: "login/LOGIN_REQUEST",
  LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS: "login/LOGIN_REQUEST_SUCCESS",
  ...
};
export const actions = {
  loginRequest: (payload) => ({
    type: types.LOGIN_REQUEST,
    payload,
  }),
...
};

Comment: I am understanding this as an action function. and... it seems to be called an action creator or an action object.

Comment: I was confused by that implementation. So, basically... watcher needs action type (I call it action name) to distinguish between multiple actions. Action type is matched with one saga function and that is all you need. When you dispatch an action you're sending action type & action payload (params) as one object called `action`. By doing so, watcher extracts `action type` and match it with saga function, calls that saga function and forwards action object (containing all other params + action type) to that particular saga function.

Comment: Let me know if you have any further question. I would open a new chat here, but I don't have that privilege at the moment.

Comment: I have now checked. Sorry. Surely, it is a bit difficult concept. I think I need to study more. SagaWatcher is watching the action type and it matches the action type to one Saga function. Is that right? And I think that there is no need to connect the action type with the saga function. Is this also correct? It’s very very difficult...

Comment: Redux Saga itself is an Redux middleware. It basically intercepts dispatched actions and try to find a saga function that could handle that dispatched action. If "action - saga" mapping is not found, it goes directly to the reducer... However if there is a saga function for that action (there is a way to define that mapping "action - saga"), saga takes that action (object) and handles "job" instead of reducer. You can call async  functions (and you should) in saga functions and also you can dispatch actions too so you can again reach reducer by doing so, or even call other sagas.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late. I read all, I think you are really good at explaining. Thanks to the explanation, I understand the saga to some extent. In particular,"It basically intercepts dispatched actions and try to find a saga function that could handle that dispatched action." This part made me understand clearly. You are kind. Thank you for your precious time. I am sad that there is no way to express it any more. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **action** is just a plain javascript object with a property `type`.  As a convention (but not a strict requirement), action objects store their data in an optional property `payload`.

An **actionCreator** is a function which takes 0 to many arguments and uses them to create an action object.

What you are seeing in the code that you posted works, but it's not ideal.  I'm guessing that certain improvements were made to the `loginModule.js` file and those improvements were not brought over to the `watcherLoginSaga.js` file.

Your `types` object allows you to use a variable such as `types.LOGIN_REQUEST` rather than the raw string `"login/LOGIN_REQUEST"`.  This has a bunch of benefits:

- you get intellisense support in your IDE for autocomplete, etc.
- you don't have to worry about making typos
- you can change the value of the underlying raw `string` and you just need to change it one place

That last one is critical, because if you were to change the value of `types.LOGIN_REQUEST` to anything other than `"login/LOGIN_REQUEST"` right now your sagas would stop working because they are using the raw string.  So you are absolutely right in thinking that the saga *should* import from the actions.  I recommend that you import your `types` and replace the strings with their corresponding variables.

The same situation is happening with the actions that the saga is dispatching via `put`.
What's going on in this code is that the saga is creating a raw action object itself from the `type` and `payload` rather than creating it though an action creator function.  That's *fine* but it's not *great*.  Like the types, action creators are a level of abstraction that allows for better code maintenance.  You could definitely extract the logic from your saga into action creator functions, if they don't exist already.

For example, your base module could include:

```
const types = {
  IS_LOGGED: "base/IS_LOGGED",
  SHOW_MODAL: "base/SHOW_MODAL"
};

export const actions = {
  isLogged: (payload) => ({
    type: types.IS_LOGGED,
    payload
  }),
  showLoginFailure: () => ({
    type: types.SHOW_MODAL,
    payload: {
      dark: true,
      modalName: "alert",
      modalContent: "login failure",
      modalStyle: "purpleGradientStyle",
      modalTitle: "Wait!"
    }
  })
};
```

And you can move the logic for creating actions away from your saga.

```
import { all, put, fork, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import { fetchData } from "store/sagas/baseSaga";
import {actions as loginActions, types as loginTypes} from "../some_path/loginModule";
import {actions as baseActions} from "../some_path/baseModule";

function* onRequestLogin(action) {
  const payload = action.payload;
  const { history } = payload;
  const successAction = (res) => {

    const cookies = new Cookies();
    cookies.set("hdmKey", res.data, {
      path: "/",
      maxAge: 3600,
    });
    return function* () {

      const payload = res;
      yield put(loginActions.getUserInfoSuccess(history));
      yield put(loginActions.loginSuccess(payload));
      yield put(baseActions.isLogged(payload));
      yield history.push("/");
    };
  };
  const failureAction = (res) => {

    return function* () {

      yield put(baseActions.showLoginFailure());
    };
  };
  yield fork(fetchData, payload, successAction, failureAction);
}

export default function* watcherLoginSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(loginTypes.LOGIN_REQUEST, onRequestLogin),
  ]);
}
```